# add hover to asp.net menu control

Tags: asp.net

i have a image menu within my asp.net website. i want to include an easy solution for hoverover functionality. for example, menu item one would dispay 1.jpg on page load and hover1.jpg when a user hovers their mouse over the image. thanks for any support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily via javascript :

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript_image_change_functions.php3